# Windows and Linux confusing and different partition info

Tags: linux, windows-10, partitioning, windows-installation, dynamic-disk

I removed my old OS to install Windows and Ubuntu alongside each other and faced a problem. Here are the steps that I did and the problem I am facing:

1. Formatted the C drive and installed Windows 10.
2. Turned off Fast-startup in Windows. There was no Secure Boot option to turn off in my BIOS. So I proceeded.
3. Created a bootable Ubuntu via Rufus and booted.
4. I selected "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10" but then asked me to select some free space on my EXTERNAL hard drive, so I clicked back and ejected my external USB hard drive.
5. The option to "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10" was no more available so I clicked on "Something Else" however it showed all my partitions with wrong sizes. So I didn't do anything there and restarted.
6. After restart I couldn't boot into Windows it would show an startup error.
7. I used the installation media and typed the following into the terminal, .

```
bootrec /FixMbr
bootrec /FixBoot
bootrec /scanos
bootrec /RebuildBcd
```

and also clicked on the "Fix Startup Problems" from Windows troubleshooter.

8. After that I could log-on to Windows however I have some problems.
9. Windows shows my disk as Invalid Dynamic Disk although it is running Windows from it.

   [image: Image #1]

   As you can see in the pic Disk Management says Invalid Dynamic Disk and it hasn't dedicated any letters to this disk. However my C drive (not D and E) is visible in the Explorer.

   [image: Image #2]
10. When I load into Ubuntu live, I can see my partitions and even mount them (I read somewhere Linux can't read dynamic disks) and add or remove data when using "Disks" app. However "GParted" shows the same wrong partition table and sizes as the Ubuntu Installation.

    [image: Image #3]

**My problems:**

1. Windows labeling disk as Invalid Dynamic Disk although it is running Windows from it. And it only shows the Windows partition (C:)
2. "GParted" and "Disks" showing different partition sizes making it impossible to install Ubuntu alongside Windows.

Please kindly help me overcome this issue safely without losing any data.
If any more info is required I would be happy to provide them.

Comment: The process you describe shouldn't have ended with this problem, so either there is some missing detail or you encountered a glitch. Either way, there isn't enough information to know what happened to put you in this situation, which is probably why this attracted a close vote.  The practical solution is to just start over.  Use your favorite Windows partitioning tool to wipe the drive and create the partitions you want (Windows tools are less likely to be problematic for Windows).  Then install Windows followed by Ubuntu, and use the Linux partitioning tools to format the Linux partitions.

Comment: What is the output of `gdisk -l /dev/sda`? (in Linux). Please [edit] the question and add this information.